# 3D array multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have arrays `A` and `B` both of dimension MxNxH.

I would like to define a binary operator, to "multiply", such that the result is MxN dimensions.

The equivalent operation would be:

```
C = A[:,:,0] * B[:,:,0] + A[:,:,1] * B[:,:,1] + .... + A[:,:,H] * B[:,:,H]
```

Is there a way to do this operation in a more efficient way?
For example, using a built in function in numpy?

*I have tried [`tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html), but this gives a different result.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is:

```
C = numpy.sum(A * B, -1)
```

I think this might work too:

```
C = numpy.einsum("...i,...i->...", A, B)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this: numpy.sum( A*B, axis=2 )

this is similar to the other suggestion but perhaps clearer (axes are numbered from 0, so axis=2 is the 3rd axis or H out of MxNxH)